# DirectX: `D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH` Ведет себя весьма странно.

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx

Здравствуйте.

Вот прототип функции: (Придумана не мной, это функция из библиотек `DX SDK`)

```
   D3DMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( 
    D3DMATRIX* pOut,
    FLOAT fovy,
    FLOAT Aspect
    FLOAT zn,
    FLOAT zf);
```

Вот эта же функция у меня в программе:

```
float Aspect = (формула расчета угла);
        D3DMATRIX matProjection;      //Объявлена структура типа D3DMATRIX        
        D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(                                      
        &matProjection,           //Указатель на структуру типа D3DMATRIX
        D3DX_PI/4.0f,             //Угол обзора
        Aspect,                   //Соотношение сторон
        10.0f,                    //Расстояние до ближайшей пл-ти сечения 
        1000.0f);                 //Расстояние до дальней пл-ти сечения
```

Все правильно и должно работать, однако компилятор указывая на последнюю строку (там где 1000.0f) пишет:

`'D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'D3DMATRIX *' to 'D3DXMATRIX *'`

Читал на англоязычных форумах, понял едва ли половину, так, что решил спросить у русскоговорящих специалистов.
Почему он переменную которая должна быть `float`, судя по сообщению компилятора пытается из `D3DMATRIX *` в `D3DMATRIX *`, это как так? Я просто не могу врубиться в смысл того, что пишет ерор лист.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть внимательно, то идет преобразование от типа D3DMATRIX* к D3DXMATRIX*. Между ними есть разница, см. MSDN: [D3DMATRIX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172573.aspx) и [D3DXMATRIX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172912.aspx). И в ф-ции Вы тоже перепутали эти разные типы...

Comment: Щя гляну, спасибо, я и не заметил эту букву Х линшюю в названиях типов...

Comment: Разобрался ,спасибо)